# How can I isolate substrings wrapped in markup tags?

Tags: javascript, html, string, algorithm, react-native

Can anyone suggest a simple* way to do the following?

```
"this is <mark>just an</mark> example <mark>snippet</mark>"
```

to

```
["this is", "<mark>just an</mark>",  "example", "<mark>snippet</mark>" ]
```

**Thanks for the answer guys**

this snippet below covers tags with attributes also

```
"<b class="highlight">Paradise</b> Lost"
.split(/(<\w+\s+(?!term).*?>.*?().*?<\/[a-zA-Z]*>)/g)
.filter((i) => i)
```

Comment: just edited the question, please have a look. @Barmar

Comment: Use `split()` with a regular expression that matches `<mark>...</mark>`. Put that in a capture group so that the delimiter will be included in the result.

Comment: Don't forget to make it non-greedy.

Comment: @Barmar Can you give a code snippet?

Comment: I told you everything you need to do. If you don't understand, read the documentation to learn.

Comment: If you can't get it working, post what you tried and we'll help.

Comment: Do see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/ to understand some of the problems with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split using regex, but considering all HTML tags and web components with attributes, not just `<mark>`.

```js
function splitHTML (inputString) {
  return inputString
    .split(/(<[a-zA-Z-](?!term).*?>.*?().*?<\/[a-zA-Z-]*>)/g)
    .filter((i) => i);
}

console.log(splitHTML('this is <mark>just an</mark> example <mark>snippet</mark>'));
```

**The code above will work for:**

- `<mark>text</mark>`
- `<my-tooltip>web component</my-tooptip>`
- `<mark class="red">colored text</mark>`

Comment: fails for this "<b class="highlight">Paradise</b> Lost"

Comment: The below works for the leftout case also
```"<b class="highlight">Paradise</b> Lost".split(/(<\w+\s+(?!term).*?>.*?().*?<\/[a-zA-Z]*>)/g)
    .filter((i) => i)```

Comment: @MuhammadAshraf Thanks for sharing! I slightly modified your regex and updated my answer

Comment: You can also add `.map((i) => i.trim())` after `.filter((i) => i)` to remove spaces on the sides. I haven't put it in the code above as it wasn't requested in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just split by regex, that will give you some empty elements.. you can filter empty elements afterwards.

```js
let a = "this is <mark>just an</mark> example <mark>snippet</mark>";
let x = a.split(/( <mark>.*?().*?<\/mark>)/g); // ['one', '.two', '.three'];
console.log(x.filter( (el) =>el) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function splitHTML (inputString) {
  const result = [];
  
  // 1. Replace a HTML tag with ###<mark> and </mark>###
  inputString = inputString.replaceAll('<mark', '###<mark');
  inputString = inputString.replaceAll('</mark>', '</mark>###');
  
  // 2. Split on the newly added sign
  inputString = inputString.split('###');
  
  // 3. Filter out empty lines and return the result
  return inputString.filter((a) => a);
}

console.log(splitHTML('this is <mark>just an</mark> example <mark>snippet</mark>')); // => ['this is ', '<mark>just an</mark>', ' example ', '<mark>snippet</mark>']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace all, it will work....

```
    <input type="text" id="text" style="width:500px; max-width: 500px;"/>
    <script>
        const value = "this is <mark>just an</mark> example <mark>snippet</mark>";
        var result = "[\"" + value.replaceAll(" <mark>", "\", \"<mark>").replaceAll("</mark> ", "</mark>\" , \"") + "\"]";
        document.getElementById("text").value   = result;
    </script>
```

Comment: I think they want an array, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar There is no such mention that he need an array, if he needs an array then he can just split using coma (,) after removing [] brackets

Comment: There are no quotes around the desired result.